# How to stop swift syntax updates in Xcode?

Tags: swift

Is there any way to stop Swift syntax updates for Xcode? The errors are quite difficult to figure out and existing projects fail to run the apps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the project in the latest xcode 7. It will automatically ask you whether you want to update the syntax or not.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes but even i choose to cancel, it opens full or red errors next time pointing to the errors based on old (previously right) code.

Comment: Which version of xcode you are using? Try xcode 6.4

Comment: Yes, it is 6.4(6E35b).

Answer (score 0):

Xcode only ships with the latest Swift version. You will need to upgrade your Swift code or stay with an older version of Xcode.